# Recursion on Request

Tags: php, symfony, recursion, request, ready

I am developing some Request with `Symfony` to get an SSL Report from SSLLabs.

**Problem:** If I send this Request, I get a Response and check one Parameter. There are three Options for this Parameter ("ERROR", "IN_PROGRESS", "READY") which I have to handle.

```
public function getSSLReport(string $request)
{
    try{
        $result = null;
        $httpClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $httpClient->request('GET', 'https://api.ssllabs.com/api/v3/analyze?host='.$request.'&all=on');
        $result = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        if($result['status'] == "READY") {
            return new JsonResponse($result);
        } else if($result['status'] == "ERROR") {
            return new JsonResponse($result['statusMessage']);
        } else {
            $this->getSSLReport($request);
        }
    }catch (\Exception $ex)
    {
        return new JsonResponse($ex);
    }
}
```

I am using some Recursion to call this Method again if the `$result` is `IN_PROGRESS`. But the Request is Pending all the Time, and canceled after 30 seconds.

If I get some Response where `"status" == "READY"` it works fine.

Comment: So the pending state is where?On $this->analyzeDomain($request) ?

Comment: The pending state is what i get as json. Its inside $result (JSON)

Comment: You might not want to hammer SSLLabs like that. There is no timeout whatsoever.

Comment: So the main problem isn't your code shown here but more the response from your analyzeDomain function to return the right state to enter the right case? Its hardly to understand cause you are not showing where your recursion happens ... Basically i would advise you to be careful with recursion especially if you are dependent on external data ...

Comment: Now you see the full Method, there happens my recursion. " $this->getSSLReport($request);"

Answer (score 1):

Add `sleep` to wait for a couple of seconds:

```
    if($result['status'] === "READY") {
        return new JsonResponse($result);
    }

    if($result['status'] === "ERROR") {
        return new JsonResponse($result['statusMessage']);
    }

    if($result['status'] === "IN_PROGRESS") {
        sleep(5);
        return $this->getSSLReport($request);
    }

    throw new \Exception('Unknown status from SSLLabs');
```

What I've changed:

- removed the `else` and replaced `elseif` by `if`.
- Replaced `==` by `====`.
- Throw an exception when the status from the API is unknown by your code. Instead of retrying, the script should exit in case of an unknown status.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. I found my Problem, it was my Ajax Call which triggered this backend.